# Lock screen Programmatically

Tags: java, android

I use this code to get pattern lock but it does not work. I want to lock the screen on button click.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lock"
        android:onClick="lock"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    }

    public void lock(View view) {
        mDPM.lockNow();
    }
}
```

I want to do like this[image]

Comment: Is your app a device admin?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html) link..

lock/unlock screen

In case it doesn't work, try android version other than ICS if you are using ICS

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens .No error display no pattern display

Comment: is there anything in your log ?